# How to merge numerical cell and char cell of binary values into 1 cell in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matlab cell of 7395X28 numerical values and i have a another character cell of 7395x8 in which there are binary values. I want the binary values cell merged into this numerical value cell without change.

For example let numerical cell be A and binary cell B i merged them  like this

C=[A,B]

This gives me a error saying you cannot merge a character cell with numerical values cell. Please anybody help me with this how to solve

The output should be a merged cell and the last column of the cell should consist of binary values. Please help.

Comment: If you can provide a minimal (non-)working example that reproduces the undesired behaviour, people will be more than happy to help you out.

Comment: I am assuming the output would be a cell array of numerical values, right?

Comment: hi sir actually the B array is a char array when i open it matlab it shows me val = 00000001 and so on, when i do as you suggested it is giving me this error  Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

Error in cell2mat (line 43)
cellclass = class(c{1});

Comment: Edit your question with some sample input and output. This might help us too in answering.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
a1 = num2cell(randi(5,2,3)) %%// cell array of numerical values
a2 = {'0' '1' '1'; '0' '1' '0' } %%// cell array of characters that are binary numbers
out = num2cell(cell2mat(a1)*10+cell2mat(a2)-'0')
```

**Output**

```
a1 = 

    [4]    [3]    [5]
    [2]    [4]    [5]


a2 = 

    '0'    '1'    '1'
    '0'    '1'    '0'


out = 

    [40]    [31]    [51]
    [20]    [41]    [50]
```

**Edit 1:**

**Code**

```
A={1,2,3;
    2,3,4;
    4,5,6;
    7,8,9;
    0,9,9}

B={'0001'; '0011'; '0111' ;'1111' ;'0101'} 

C = [A cellstr(cell2mat(B))]
```

**Output**

```
C = 

    [1]    [2]    [3]    '0001'
    [2]    [3]    [4]    '0011'
    [4]    [5]    [6]    '0111'
    [7]    [8]    [9]    '1111'
    [0]    [9]    [9]    '0101'
```

**Edit 2:**

**Code**

```
A={1,2,3;
    2,3,4;
    4,5,6;
    7,8,9;
    0,9,9}

B = ['00000001';'00010001';'00000001';'10110001';'01010011']

C = [A cellstr(B)]
```

**Output**

```
C = 

    [1]    [2]    [3]    '00000001'
    [2]    [3]    [4]    '00010001'
    [4]    [5]    [6]    '00000001'
    [7]    [8]    [9]    '10110001'
    [0]    [9]    [9]    '01010011'
```

Comment: No if A={1,2,3
         2,3,4
         4,5,6
         7,8,9
         0,9,9}
and B={0001
       0011
       0111
       1111
       0101}

then C={1,2,3,0001
        2,3,4,0011
        4,5,6,0111
        7,8,9,1111
        0,9,9,0101}
Hope i made myself clear

Comment: So, if when I merge 7395X28 and 7395x8, I would get a cell arary of 7395X29 size?

Comment: @Hari Check out Edit -1, hope this is what you were after.

Comment: @Hari Check out Edit 2, Really hoping this time it works for you!

Comment: Sir still getting error let me explain it to clearly from start i have a data set with different features each feature is imported into matlab in different cells. All the features have numerical values except 1 which consists of string values i converted those string values into binary using this code B = dec2bin(cellfun(@(string) find(strcmp(string, unique(alchemycategory, 'stable')), 1, 'first'), alchemycategory), 8);
after that i merged all numerical feature cells into 1 and i want to merge the binary cell into it but i am unable do it please help

Comment: Provide sample input, output in your question? You can edit your question you know. Also, what's the error you are getting using Edit -2?

Comment: i am not a sure how to provide sample input and sample output because its a huge data i have already give you the sample error for edit 2 is Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Comment: @Hari If you are still stuck with it, I would suggest uploading the input data somewhere and link it here.